# Ternary operator in argument(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

Hello guys it's my first try to ask anything here
I'm reading **eloquent javascript** book and here in *chapter 4 i* see this

```
function range(start, end, step = start < end ? 1 : -1) {
  let array = [];

  if (step > 0) {
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) array.push(i);
  } else {
    for (let i = start; i >= end; i += step) array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}
```

I can't understand why this code needs this | = `start < end ? 1 : -1` | because when we change it on 1 nothing gonna change (how i chacked).

```
function range(start, end, step = 1) {
  let array = [];

  if (step > 0) {
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) array.push(i);
  } else {
    for (let i = start; i >= end; i += step) array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Solved: code with | 1 | when it has only 2 arguments gonna be wrong, so ternary operator was needed

Comment: If start is greater than end it will break.  The step code prevents that.

Comment: oops my bad i didnt chacked the code whith | 1 | when it has only 2 argument, without ternar operator that dont work.
Big thanks to community and all who answered to my question

Answer (score 0):

This means "step defaults to `1` if `start < end`, otherwise step defaults to `0`".

Comment: Else value Is - 1 not 0

Answer (score 0):

This ternary operator is syntax sugar for an `if...else` statement.

When you see something like `var result = isTrue == true ? 'is true indeed' : 'not that true'`;

it would be the same as:

```
var result;
if(isTrue == true) {
    result = 'is true indeed'
}
else {
    result = 'not that true'
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the "syntax sugar" here — You _literally_ could not replace that ternary with an if/else statement in this case. Statement _vs_ expression.

Comment: "Syntax sugar" was a bad translation I made. Syntactic sugar would be the correct translation. Syntatic sugar would be defined as: syntactic sugar is syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express. 

What I meant by syntactic sugar is that the ternary operator is another way to express an If/else statement. I agree that it __could not__ be replaced directly where it is. Although it could be placed directly at the beginning of the function with an "if/else". Syntactic sugar can always be replaced by its equivalent form.